# Ударение в стихотворении

Tags: литература, литературоведение

Можно ли менять ударения в некоторых словах стихотворения, если получается рифма?

Comment: Конкретный вопрос нужен: какое слово, какая рифма...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно нельзя! Неправильные ударения в стихах допустимы, если они используются нарочито и с определённой художественной целью.

Посмотрите для общего понимания статью [Ударение в поэзии: норма или поэтическая вольность](https://moluch.ru/conf/phil/archive/178/10113/) (почти в самом начале сборника по ссылке) и обратите внимание на окончательный вывод из анализа рассмотренных стихотворений:

> Как видим, широко распространенное мнение о поэтической вольности как
>   индульгенции на ошибку не подтверждается фактами: ни одного случая
>   случайной неправильности, ни одного случая вольности, заданной
>   исключительно ритмом.

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Answer (score -3):

Вообще, это не очень хорошо. Однако есть небольшая лазейка: нѣкоторыя слова ранѣе ударялись по-другому, напримѣръ: илИ, Уже. Тогда на вопросъ о странномъ удареніи можно выдать законный отвѣтъ: кошу подъ старину. Посмотрѣть ударенія можно въ акцентологическихъ словаряхъ древнерусскаго языка, и, желательно конечно освоить теорію акцентныхъ парадигмъ.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, не могли бы вы писать, используя современные нормы русской орфографии?

Comment: Уважаемый Aer, нѣтъ, я не могу писать используя иную орѳографію, такъ какъ предпочитаю болѣе совершенный инструментъ менѣе совершенному.

Comment: И это прискорбно, так как многие могут испытывать трудности при чтении ваших сообщений; если вы рассчитываете помочь людям, а не продемонстрировать увлечение древностями, то возникают вопросы...